# End of Arrayformula Range in Google Sheets by source cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Is it possible to parse the end line 3 into a Arrayformula. So the in Cell X1 is number  3 stored, the last line should by 3.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(A1:A3 <> "" ;true;false)
)
```

When I use INDIRECT, I have to store the complete range in the cell X1 ( like A1:A3), but I want to store only the line number 3 in cell X1.

This tried this formula, but it's not working:

```
=arrayformula(
IF(A1:A & X1 <> "";true;false)
)
```

Many many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula(if(indirect("A1:A"&X1) <> "";true;false))
```

Comment: Thats was lighting fastü. It's working perfect.